# How can I find out if an Expression is writeable?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

Based on some user input, I dynamically compose an `Expression`. Now, I need to distinguish the case where this expression is writable from the case where it's not. An example of a writable expression is a property expression referring to a property with a setter. A non-writable expression would for example be a call to a method.

The Expressions library raises an `ArgumentExpression` when trying to assign to a non-writable expression. So currently, I have:

```
try
{
    assign = Expression.Assign(prop2, prop1);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    ...
}
```

which for various reasons isn't the greatest code. I wonder if someone knows a better way.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for `Expression.Assign`. You'll see a method 'RequiresCanWrite'. See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/Expression.cs#L308

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hint by Ian Mercer, I've ended up with:

```
    private static bool IsWriteable(Expression expression)
    {
        switch (expression.NodeType)
        {
            case ExpressionType.Index:
                PropertyInfo indexer = ((IndexExpression)expression).Indexer;
                if (indexer == null || indexer.CanWrite)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
                MemberInfo member = ((MemberExpression)expression).Member;
                PropertyInfo prop = member as PropertyInfo;
                if (prop != null)
                {
                    if (prop.CanWrite)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Assert(member is FieldInfo);
                    FieldInfo field = (FieldInfo)member;
                    if (!(field.IsInitOnly || field.IsLiteral))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It should be stated that in general `case ExpressionType.Parameter` also should return `true`.